# How do I call a constructor within a method in the same class?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I need to refresh some variables set by a constructor, therefore I thought about recalling it.

How do I do this within a method in the same class? I would like to keep the same instance.

```
this();
```

> Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

It seems I could only do this within another constructor, at its first line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better to move your initialization code to some method (`init()`) which you will call from constructor, as well from every other place where you need it.

Constructors shouldn't be considered as being like any other method. Their purpose is to create new instances of the class, so calling one from that object's method can't result in changing the caller's instance variables.

Comment: I thought about it, but it would be less readable. Why should I do that if Java provides constructors? They are methods, too, then why shouldn't I use them?

Comment: @joiner They are not methods, not according to the Java Language Specification, ie. to Java compilers. They are constructors.

Comment: However, they have a body.

Comment: They also have parameters. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: That does not matter.

Comment: Constructors have bodies but they are not methods. If you call a constructor, you create a completely new instance. That instance can't be the instance that called the constructor in the first place, it just wouldn't make any sense. It would be like giving birth to yourself.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I could call a constructor from another, and it does not create a new instance.

Comment: That's part of the language. When you're in a constructor, you're still initializing the instance, that's what a constructor is for.